# Как обновить интерфейс при работе с Alamofire

Tags: swift, api, url, uicollectionview, alamofire

Есть api (https://docs.api.jikan.moe/#section/Information). Получаю с нее данные, но никак не могу отобразить их в своих collection view. Данные должны приходить, я проверял.
Заполнение ячеек collection view реализую через view model [ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ9qF.png) <-> [ViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsLgN.png)

Менеджер по работе с API [NetworkManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLaq3.png)

В итоге просто получаются белые collectionView - [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5esC.jpg)

Первый раз решил поработать с Alamofire и видимо чего-то не понимаю. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. [Ссылка на github](https://github.com/Shalai-Ivan/Anime-Store) если вдруг кому-то понадобится.

> Дополнено

Я кажется нашел в чем причина. Она вот в этом блоке кода, когда извлекаются данные и массивов моделей (пустой) возвращается раньше, чем происходит их добавление. Как можно это исправить и сделать грамотнее? [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRsMk.png)

```
func fetchRequest(typeRequest: TypeRequest) -> [AnimeModel] {
var animeModels: [AnimeModel] = []
switch typeRequest {
case .name(let name):
    let urlString = "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?q=\(name)"
    AF.request(urlString).response { response in
        guard let data = response.data else { return print("NO DATA FOR - \(name)") }
        do {
            let json = try JSON(data: data)
            let title = json["data"][0]["title_english"].string ?? "Anime"
            let imageURL = json["data"][0]["images"]["jpg"]["image_url"].string ?? ""
            let image = AnimeModel.downloadImage(stringURL: imageURL)
            animeModels.append(AnimeModel(image: image, title: title))
            print(".NAME ANIME MODELS - \(animeModels)")
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
print("BEFORE RETURN ANIME MODELS - \(animeModels)")
return animeModels    // -> Возвращает пустой массив, а только потом срабатывает animeModels.append()
```

}

Comment: попробуйте из вашего проекта создать минимальный пример с минимумом кода и добавить его здесь в вопрос в виде текста, а не скриншотов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @schmidt9 Обновил вопрос

Comment: Повторю, добавьте код в виде текста,а не картинки, чтобы его можно было например скопировать

Comment: @schmidt9 Добавил текст функции в которой проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку запросы выполняются асинхронно, вы можете использовать коллбэк `completion`, чтобы вернуть результат. Также можете попробовать реализовать подобный механизм с помощью [async/await](https://habr.com/ru/company/citymobil/blog/571360/)

```
class NetworkManager {
    func fetchRequest(typeRequest: TypeRequest,
                      completion: @escaping ([AnimeModel]) -> Void) {
        var animeModels: [AnimeModel] = []
        switch typeRequest {
        case .name(let name):
            let urlString = "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?q=\(name)"
            AF.request(urlString).response { response in
                guard let data = response.data else { return print("NO DATA FOR - \(name)") }
                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: data)
                    let title = json["data"][0]["title_english"].string ?? "Anime"
                    let imageURL = json["data"][0]["images"]["jpg"]["image_url"].string ?? ""
                    let image = AnimeModel.downloadImage(stringURL: imageURL)
                    animeModels.append(AnimeModel(image: image, title: title))
                    completion(animeModels) // <<<<<
                } catch let DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context) {
                    print(context)
                } catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, context) {
                    print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
                    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                } catch let DecodingError.valueNotFound(value, context) {
                    print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
                    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                } catch let DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)  {
                    print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
                    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                } catch {
                    print("error: ", error)
                }
            }
        case .apiTop:
            let urlString = "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime?limit=10"
            AF.request(urlString).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                guard let data = response.data else { return print("NO DATA FOR APITOP")}
                do {
                    let animeData = try JSONDecoder().decode(AnimeData.self, from: data)
                    animeModels = AnimeModel.getArray(animeData: animeData)
                    completion(animeModels) // <<<<<
                } catch let DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context) {
                    print(context)
                } catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, context) {
                    print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
                    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                } catch let DecodingError.valueNotFound(value, context) {
                    print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
                    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                } catch let DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)  {
                    print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
                    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                } catch {
                    print("error: ", error)
                }
            })
        }
    }
   
}
```